# Do Web Audio Api and Supercollider work together?

Tags: javascript, apache, web-audio-api, supercollider

Is it possible to load a SuperCollider `SynthDef` as a source into `Web Audio API`?

Say, if I have an `Apache Server` running on `port 8888`, can I set `SC` to the same server and do the trick on real time?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need the server to be able to stream audio (Icecast, or Shoutcast type) to the client. Then you'll be able to pipe that into WebAudio.